# IntelliJ can't resolve symbol despite adding library

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am creating an external library to share code between my client/server programs. IntelliJ can't seem to import this jar file and I can't understand why, I followed all the advice I've found online.

I added the jar to my `lib` folder and added it as a library in my main module (it's called 'common':
[image: modules setting screen]

This is the error (repeated on each instance of me using `User` or `Packet`). On import statements it says "package common does not exist":
[image: cannot find symbol error]

I've tried invalidating caches and that didn't seem to work either. I tried this same import on a new project just to see if I was doing anything wrong and it worked perfectly on that new project so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

EDIT:
I've noticed that this error only happens in files that are in packages within the `src` folder. So basically, `Main` can find the jar because it is only in the src folder, but `RegistrationController` can't because it's in `src/communication`.

Comment: just rebuild your project

Comment: It has the same error as the second screenshot.

Comment: did you add this library in your project path ?

Comment: It's in secexj-gui/lib (the same place I have javafx stored which is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the shared code I was making was not in a package, just a `src` folder. Because of that, the code that was in my default package (`src`) could access the classes, but not the code in packages. To fix this, I put the shared classes in a package (`com`), exported them as a jar, and imported that into my project. Now, my packages can do `com.Packet` or `com.User` and get the files successfully.